# Encode String From strftime

Tags: php, string, date, strftime

I have this code:

```
strftime("%A %d %B %Y" ,strtotime($res['date']))
```

it prints: luned� 15 settembre 2014

but it could prints: lunedì 15 settembre 2014 i've charset UTF8 on top page, i try to do:

```
str_replace("ì" , "&#236;" , strftime("%A %d %B %Y" ,strtotime($res['date'])));
```

but it doesn't work, how i can replace the � to ì ?

I've resolve it with utf8_decode and after i've replace ? with ì

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an encoding problem you probably need to put utf8_decode on your result

Try this :

```
$var = strftime("%A %d %B %Y" ,strtotime($res['date']));
$var = utf8_decode($var);
echo $var; // If there is any special character it will be well printed for example
           //  ì
```

Comment: it  prints ? instead ì

Comment: @Carbos Yeah on my computer it works well. When you echo $var what does it print now ?

Comment: this is the output: luned? 15 settembre 2014

Comment: I've resolve it, after i use utf8_decode i replace ? with ì because with "day" the only special var is ì

Answer (score 0):

are you using  the correct encoding for your html page?

works fine on HTML5 on my browser : test.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');
echo  strftime("%A %d %B %Y" ,strtotime());   
?>
</body>
</html>
```

output: giovedì 01 gennaio 1970

Comment: added example so if u use <html5 you have to add meta charset="utf-8" to support this